# Best Method of copying partition in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, parquet, impala

So, I have a use case where I want to copy the last partition of the table and insert it in the same table with new partition column value.

Its important to note that last partition value is always known.

I can think of two ways of doing this

1. Get `where partitionColumn = partitionValue` in a `DataFrame` and change the partition value using `.withColumn` and then `saveAsTable` and then do Invalidate/Refresh
2. OR,

   1. Copy the `parquet` files from the last partition directory
   2. Create new partition, paste it in new directory with `/newPatritionValue/` at the end
   3. Paste the parquet files
   4. Run `ALTER TABLE`

Which would run faster?

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? Why would you need the same data in two partitions?

Comment: Its because of the use case. This is a weekly job. We are supposed to keep old data in new partition if we don't see new dumps (files on edge node).

Answer (score 0):

I think **approach 1** will have some additional overhead. Spark may attempt to write files differently (it may be number of files or compression or even some schema modifications) because from it's point of view your are reading one dataset and then output another.

With **approach 2** you simply copy the files to another folder, data will be exactly the same after copy. Also you can even replace your `ALTER TABLE .. ADD PARTITION .. LOCATION ..` with `MSCK REPAIR TABLE ..`, it will make your code cleaner since less params are passed around.

Your (and your team) preferences also matter. If all of your workflows are already in Spark, it will make more harm in a long run to add some other type of jobs.